# Qt spell check on mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, qt, spell-checking

I am porting a windows only application to run on mac as well using Qt. We had a third party library for the spell checking on windows which isn't available for OS X. I would like to tie into `NSSpellchecker` using Objective-C or Objective-C++. I have looked around quite a bit and found one half solution of using a custom widget. We would prefer to have it abstracted out in a class that checks instead of the widget so as to not have to use a different widget depending on operating system. I am confident in my ability to write the class for checking and that shouldn't be an issue.

My question is if I will need to create a custom UI that houses the suggestions/options or if OS X has a stock spelling grammar panel that we can just tie into?

Does anyone have experience doing spell check with Qt on Mac? We are using Qt 4.8+ and targeting Win7 / Snow Leopard.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but have a look at http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2007/10/12/spellchecking-for-qtextedit-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I don't know and I don't think there's a stock Qt widget to do it. This list covers pretty much every Qt widget you can use: [enter link description here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtgui.html)

As a solution you can use hunspell (http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) directly even on Windows. It's used in Libre and Open Office and also used by MacOSX.

And to implement it you can use QCompleter ([enter link description here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html)).